# PHP + MySQL profiler

Tags: mysql, profiling

You know how vBulletin has a sql profiler when in debug mode? How would I go about building one for my own web application? It's built in procedural PHP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html

The above link links how you can get al the sql profile information after any query.

Best way to implement it is to create a database class and have it have a "profile" flag to turn on logging of queries and the appropriate information as shown int he link above.

Example:

```
Class dbthing{
  var $profile = false;

  function __construct($profile = false){
    if($profile){
      $this->query('set profiling=1');
      $this->profile = true;
    }
    ...
  }

  function query($sql, $profile_this == false){
     ...
     if($this->profile && !$profile_this)
        $this->query("select sum(duration) as qtime from information_schema.profiling where query_id=1", true);
     ... // store the timing here
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use a database connection wrapper that I can place a profiling wrapper arround. This way I can discard the wrapper, or change it, without changing my base connector class.

```
class dbcon {
    function query( $q ) {}
}
class profiled_dbcon()
{
    private $dbcon;
    private $thresh;
    function __construct( dbcon $d, $thresh=false )
    {
        $this->dbcon = $d;
        $this->thresh = $thresh;
    }
    function queury( $q )
    { 
        $begin = microtime( true );
        $result = this->dbcon->query();
        $end = microtime( true );
        if( $this->thresh && ($end - $begin) >= $this->thresh ) error_log( ... );
        return $result;  
    }
}
```

For profiling with a 10 second threshold:

```
$dbc = new profiled_dbcon( new dbcon(), 10 );
```

I have it use error_log() what the times were. I would not log query performance back to the database server, that affects the database server performance. You'd rather have your web-heads absorb that impact.

Comment: This would not give an accurate result simply because microtime() provides the server time and not the actual amount of processor time needed for an operation (or HD access time etc.) it is best to use the mysql built in functions to get how long a process took

Comment: @mike v: very good point. Thanks for posting the link about mysql profiler feature, I'm happy to learn more about that.

Comment: aren't you just creating work for yourself? why not just use the mysql slow query log?

Comment: If you're developing against a stock mysql 5.0 system and you don't have the option to add sub-second slow query log patches to your database then this this becomes your next option.

Answer (score 1):

Though late, [Open PHP MyProfiler](http://www.php-trivandrum.org/open-php-myprofiler/) would help you achieve this, and you can extract functional sections from the code for your usage.